# How to cancel notification in onDestroy function

Tags: java, android, android-notifications

i want to make a notification like BBM connected notification (for android)...
so when i open my app, the notification will appear, and it cant be canceled...
so i use this code

```
    nm=(NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notification=new Notification(android.R.drawable.stat_notify_more, "this is important", System.currentTimeMillis());
    notification.flags = notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;  //notification never dissapear
    Context context=MainActivity.this;
    CharSequence title="hello there";
    CharSequence detail="this is demo";
    Intent intent=new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent  pending=PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, detail, pending);
    nm.notify(0, notification);
```

i put that code in public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)...
so, the notification cant cancel when i click or slide.
and when i close my app, the notification still there.
then i have an idea to use this code :

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    nm.cancelAll();
}
```

but, this function never called???

how can i cancel the notification when i close the app?

Answer (score 2):

It might be because onDestroy will not be called immediately when you navigate away with the home button.

Android has callback methods available that work well with notifications etc.
These are called `onUserLeaveHint()` and `onUserInteraction()`.

The JavaDoc for onUserLeaveHint() states:

> Called as part of the activity lifecycle when an activity is about to
>   go into the background as the result of user choice. For example, when
>   the user presses the Home key, onUserLeaveHint() will be called, but
>   when an incoming phone call causes the in-call Activity to be
>   automatically brought to the foreground, onUserLeaveHint() will not be
>   called on the activity being interrupted. In cases when it is invoked,
>   this method is called right before the activity's onPause() callback.
>
> This callback and onUserInteraction() are intended to help activities
>   manage status bar notifications intelligently; specifically, for
>   helping activities determine the proper time to cancel a notfication.

I'd suppose you will want to override either one of these; especially onUserLeaveHint() seems a good choice for your purpose.

```
@Override
protected void onUserLeaveHint()
{
    nm.cancelAll();
    super.onUserLeaveHint();
}
```

You can't intercept the event of 'force closing' the application process. Android doesn't support this. When the user does this, the system calls [Process.killProcess(int pid)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Process.html#killProcess%28int%29) and all resources will be freed. It's just not possible to catch this event and perform tasks before the process is really killed. Maybe a workaround is possible, but it wouldn't be how Android wants it.

Comment: the previous answer works, and your answer works too, but i need the cancelation when app close by pressing home button or apps menu then swipe the app to close it...

Comment: If you have several activities and the notification must be there no matter which one is showing, it's going to be a little harder. There is no real callback available for when the whole application is closed. I've found another option though, will update my answer with it.

Comment: sorry, its still not the answer that i want...because i want a handler that run when i close my app using like task manager or the hardclose...

Comment: You can't intercept/catch those events. The system will simply kill the app process and no callback methods are called anymore.

Answer (score 0):

There is no guarantee that the method will called. If application will not have enough memory, it can be killed by OS.

> There are situations where the system will simply kill the activity's hosting process without calling this method (or any others) in it, so it should not be used to do things that are intended to remain around after the process goes away.

Comment: the onDestroy function is called now, but when i close the app using hard way, press the apps menu button or hold the home button, then swipe the app. this method doesnt called onDestroy...

Comment: When you press the home button, app doesn't destroyed, it's minimized. So, if you need cancel the notification do this when onStop called

Answer (score -1):

You missed the super.onDestroy

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    nm.cancelAll();
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Comment: its still not called when i close my app using the hard way, using home button then swipe the app...